# Is there a way to get CAT.NET rules in FxCop 10.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, fxcop, cat.net

FxCop does not cover many vulnerabilities like XSS, SQL injection etc.
These vulnerabilities were taken care of by CAT.NET earlier.
CAT.NET is compatible with FxCop 1.35 but not FxCop 10.0.

Is there any way I can get those rules in FxCop 10.0??

PS: The code to be analyzed is not compatible with VS 2008 as it was written with a newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CAT.NET assemblies would need to be updated to reference the newer FxCop assemblies, and the CAT.NET code would need to be modified to address any breaking changes in FxCop (of which, IIRC, there were quite a few between the relevant versions).

Comment: Any example or any guide for the same?
Anything that I can refer to??

And do I need to get the source code of the DLL of CAT.NET and then make the changes?